# SizetoFit versus UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight. What is the difference?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I had always been told that if I have a UILabel with dynamic text content in it that I should use SizeToFit as that would adjust the UILabel properly. I used sizeToFit but it was messing up my text labels that were on a UITableViewCell after I did a scroll. However on initial screen load, they would appear fine.

After messing with it for a couple of hours I read somewhere that someone else had the same issue and that instead of SizeToFit they used the following two lines:

```
 cell.message.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.message.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

and it would work. Well I did and my UILabels are perfect. However I am still curious in understanding why so?

so now my code looks like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessagesCustomViewCell";
    MessagesCustomViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MessagesCustomViewCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];  //you can also loop thru or manually remember positions
    }

    NSArray * discussion = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      cell.author.text = [discussion valueForKeyPath:@"author.name"];
      cell.message.text = [discussion valueForKey:@"text"]; //DYNAMIC VARIABLE SIZED TEXT 


    cell.message.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.message.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**sizeToFit**

***behavior:care about its content over superview's size***

send `sizeToFit` to a UILabel without `[yourLabel setNumberOfLines:0]` will make the Label as wide as possible to fit it's text. While with `[yourLabel setNumberOfLines:0]` your label will break it's text to mutiple lines according it's width, but this will make it's height as large as possible to fit in it's text, it does not care about it's superview's bounds.

**autoResizingMask**

***behavior:care about superview's size over its content***

If a UIlabel's autoResizingMask is set, once it's superview's bounds is change, it will change it's frame first, then it checks "Can i put more text in my rect?" base on it's relative properties(numberOfLines, font,...).